# Google MDL Waterfall header not shrinking on scroll and scroll bar on right of body

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

DataThe following shows the header and main body of a Google MDL Page. I'm trying to use a waterfall header - where the header shrinks as you scroll.

With the page below what I am getting is that the header does not scroll and I get a scroll bar on the right of the body.

So how would I set this up so the Waterfall header shrinks? Browser is IE10)

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout--waterfall">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <div class="mdl-layout__title">
                Document Management
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
              mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right" id="searchBox">
                <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="srchText">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </label>
                <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="srchText" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">

        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-grid search-result-width page-content" id="contentGrid">
            <!--Dummy--> 
            <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp card-width">
                <div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__title">
                        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">
                            Name
                        </h2>
                        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                        <p>
                            An Address                          </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" href="patientDocumentList.html?Id=08029aa4800b0ff6">DETAILS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `<header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall">` you've missed the `mdl-layout__header--waterfall` as you've written `mdl-layout--waterfall`